# Angular prevent re-render when item of array gets updated

Tags: angular

I have a component where I loop over an array to display the items it has;

```
<div *ngFor="let field of requirement.requirementFields; let i = index">
  <requirement-field (data)="handleReqData(i, $event)"></requirement-field>
</div>
```

Now the child `requirement-field` has bunch of inputs. When the values of these input changes I'm emitting an event `data`. I need to keep the items `requirmentFields` array updated with changes happening inside each requirment-field. So, I'm doing this:

```
  handleReqData(i: number, data: IRequirementField) {
    this.requirement.requirementFields[i] = {...data};
  }
```

But as soon as the item in the array is updated (because of `handleReqData`) There is a visible flash on the screen telling me that the angular is re-rendering the list. Moreover, after the flash requirement-fields' data has been reset and does not reflect what is there in the requirementFields arary. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: U mean `requirementFields` is not updating ? can u create a minimal stackblitz, so we can debug

Comment: You probably want to introduce a trackBy function in the loop so Angular knows it only has to update certain parts instead of having to re-render the entire list..